# Symfony 2.4 custom response for dropped session

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.4

I'm developing a RESTful interface in my application (utilizing FOSRestBundle), and I want it to always return some meaningful JSON response even if non-interactive authentication fails (e.g. user was locked during his login session). Now it just redirect to the login page.

I though I could implement it using Core Exception Listener of some sorts, but I don't know what exceptions to listen for or if it even possible.

Some hints will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the 'is loggedin constraint' from the route.

For example if you have something like this in your `security.yml` `- { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }` you have to replace with it `- { path: ^/admin, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }` and check if he is loggedin in your controller.
To check the role of the user in the controller use

```
$securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
if( $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY') ){  
   return;//send error json

}
//is logged in and authorized
```

When he is in fact logged in just proceed as usual, else send your custom response.

I strongly not advise you to do this since you have more code to maintain and there are more mistakes to be made, more so if you want to protect data.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. First of all, I don't have a problem with authorization exceptions - they are handled fine by FosRestBundle's Exception Controller. The problem I have is with dropped sessions. For example when user was marked as "inactive" or was banned during his login session.